# Edit list of objects with a custom Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, clone, edit

I'm trying to figure out how to display a list of objects (and just a few certain fields) in a lightning component and expose those fields for editing. What my full app is supposed to do is clone a custom object and it's children and then open a screen for editing them all at once. I can't figure out how to get my save button to actually save the field edits. Please let me know if you can help.

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="EventCloneController" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" >
<!-- This is automatically populated because of force:hasRecordId above -->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

    <!-- This is where the events are held -->
<aura:attribute name="Events" type="Event__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="EventLength" type="Integer"/>

<!-- Calls the JS controller which calls the Apex controller on load. Name must = init to get this to run on load -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />


<!-- Show alerts -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!(!empty(v.Events))}">  
        <div class="" style="width:100%;">
            <h1 class="alertText" >Enter dates for each Event:&nbsp;</h1> 
          <!--  create form to take input -->
            <form class="slds-form--stacked">
            <div>
                <ui:button press="{!c.saveEdits}" label="Clone Event"/>
            </div>
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">    

                      <aura:iteration items="{!v.Events}" var="event" indexVar="i"> 
                          <div class="slds-col slds-m-around--medium"> 

                                 <ui:inputText aura:id="Name" label="Name"
                                      class="slds-input"
                                      labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                      value="{!event.Name}"
                                      required="false"
                                      aura:Id = "EventName" /><br />
                                <ui:inputDateTime aura:id="startdate" label="Event Start Date: "
                                      class="slds-input"
                                      labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                      value="{!event.Start_Date_Time__c}"
                                      displayDatePicker="true"
                                      required="false"
                                      aura:Id = "EventStart" /> 
                                <ui:inputDateTime aura:id="enddate" label="Event End Date: "
                                      class="slds-input"
                                      labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                      value="{!event.End_Date_Time__c}"
                                      displayDatePicker="true"
                                      required="false"
                                      aura:Id = "EventEnd" /> 
                            </div>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>

    </div>

</aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.cloneEvents");
    action.setParams({
        "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    // Register the callback function
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var results = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.Events", results);
            component.set("v.EventLength", results.length);
        }
    });
    // Invoke the service
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

saveEdits : function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveEdits");
    action.setParams({
        "eventList": component.get("v.Events")
    });
    // Register the callback function
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var results = response.getReturnValue();
            var location = "/one/one.app?#/sObject/" + results + "/view";
            parent.window.location.href=location;
        } else {
            alert(state);
        }
    });
    // Invoke the service
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}

})
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class EventCloneController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Event__c> cloneEvents(ID recordId){
        List<Event__c> eventsToAdd = new List<Event__c>();
        try{
            List<Event__c> events = [Select Id, Name, Start_Date_Time__c, End_Date_Time__c, Parent_Event__c  
            FROM Event__c WHERE ID = :recordId OR Parent_Event__c = :recordId];

            Event__c firstEvent;
            ID newRecordId;

            for(Event__c event : events){
                if(event.Parent_Event__c == null){
                    Event__c newEvent2 = event.clone();                 
                    insert newEvent2;
                    newRecordId = newevent2.id;
                    firstEvent = newEvent2;
                    eventsToAdd.add(newEvent2);
                }
                break;
            }
            for(Event__c event : events){
                Event__c newEvent = event.clone();

                if(event.Parent_Event__c != null){
                    newEvent.Parent_Event__c = newRecordId;
                    eventsToAdd.add(newEvent);              
                }
            }

            if(eventsToAdd.size() > 0){
                upsert eventsToAdd;
            }

            return eventsToAdd;
        } catch(Exception e){
            String errorMessage = 'Error: ' + e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getStackTraceString();
            system.debug(errorMessage);
            return eventsToAdd;
        }


    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveEdits(List<Event__c> eventList){
        String parentId = '';
        try{
            for(Event__c e : eventList){
                if(e.Parent_Event__c == null){
                    parentId = e.id;
                    break;
                }
            }
            update eventList;
        } catch(Exception e){
            String errorMessage = 'Error: ' + e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getStackTraceString();
            system.debug(errorMessage);
        }

        return parentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem, your code looks OK in general, this approach should work. Can you explain better why this does not work?

Comment: When I change one of the input fields for the record and then click my button, nothing happens. The Event__c record just stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! My JS and Apex methods had the same name. Doh!